# Fastclick.js integration with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, touch

I'm building a Cordova application and click response times are slow.

I [found](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch) the [angular-touch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) plugin for Angular (which, while designed for Angular 1.2.0, looks like it would likely work with older versions of Angular, as it's really just a set of directives) but upon trying it out, I didn't get the results I wanted. Clicks still aren't firing on tap.

From what I understand, [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) is a more stable alternative to angular-touch at the moment (as angular-touch is still in development). I, however, want my `ng-click` directives to take advantage of fastclick.

How can I integrate fastclick.js with angular - can I just include the file and init the script, or do I have to wrap fastclick behavior in `ng-click` (essentially what angular-touch does with its first-party code)?

Note: My app is using Angular 1.0, as it was built before the stable release.

Comment: If clicks aren't firing on tap then you did something wrong. I've used `ng-click` many times and it always worked like a charm. Maybe show us some simplified code.

Comment: As an alternative you could try: https://github.com/randallb/angular-hammer, which provides directives for binding hammer.js to angular.js.

Comment: @TheHippo Sorry, wasn't clear. Clicks are firing, but after the 300ms delay, is what I meant. This makes everything fairly unresponsive. Honestly, this could be fine for the app, but if possible, I'd like to make it better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was simpler than I thought; I anticipated having to modify some angular directives, but it turns out that this is just a drop-in library. I included it before my angular library and saw instant results in my phonegap application (after calling `new FastClick` per the fastclick documentation).

So far, I can't find any downsides to this method. I thought that there might be some issues with the `document.ready`-type setup call (instead of something more integrated into Angular), but there don't seem to be any timing issues or anything.

Worth noting for anyone who stumbles onto this question - I'm only using the tap functionality; I believe that fastclick exposes some extra functionality that I'm not using for this project.

Comment: Did you try instantiating the FastClick inside a main controller instead of on document.ready?

Comment: @HampusAhlgren For my use case, I didn't. However, you might be able to instantiate it as part of your angular module config, perhaps. You probably could do it in a controller if you wanted, maybe? Why do you ask?

Comment: Does anyone know what the issues are between angular and fastclick as mentioned in [this article](http://blog.ionic.io/hybrid-apps-and-the-curse-of-the-300ms-delay) from ionic? As of Sept-2015 I have not found any conflicts yet.

Comment: Apparently fastclick is not triggered by ngClick directive attached to elements

Answer (score 13):

From [this page](http://aslamhadi.com/integrate-fastclick-js-with-angularjs/): the "Angular way" is to `.run` the FastClick initializer in your Angular JS file. Make sure to load the `fastclick.js` module before your Angular code.

HTML:

```
<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
```

in app.js:

```
app.run(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

Comment: It would be even more Angular friendly if you injected FastClick as a constant and used the `$document` service :)

Comment: @gustavohenke I'm not sure that's how constants are supposed to be used.

Comment: @Blazemonger in terms of testability, yes, because FastClick is an global variable, so you can properly mock it, instead of doing nasty hacks while testing. Source: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#style-y240

Comment: If you don't want to use globals inside the angular context, use `$window.FastClick.attach($window.document.body);`