# Implement Fastclick with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, fastclick.js, fastclick

(Premise: i just found another Question talking about this problem but it's dated 2013 and it is not working for me.)

Problem: How can i implement Fastclick in a mobile app based on Angularjs and Angular-material, developed on the Ionic Framework?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427604/fastclick-js-integration-with-angularjs

Comment: yes, i was talking about it. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I completely ignored that first line. I'm interested in the answer to this too.

Comment: I loaded fastclick.js file in the head of my .html file, and not where the angular template advise to put it. Now it works! (or it seems working)